# Using dry moly lube as an alternative to anti-seize

Tags: o2-sensor, anti-seize

While shopping for some anti-seize for my O2 sensor install, I came across some transmission lube that had me wondering about whether I could use it as an alternative to anti-seize.

It appears to have the functionality expected of anti-seize in an O2 sensor application

- High temperature resistance (the can says 700 °F)
- Prevention of two dissimilar materials from fusing by forming a coating on the surface it is sprayed
- Durability (assuming this if it is meant for transmissions which see waaay more wear and tear than the average O2 sensor

The motivation behind this question is the apparent scarcity of anti-seize compound in my quarters; I had to spend a good couple of hours before finding a place that actually had some in stock. It would be useful to know for future reference that one can get by with an alternative product that provides similar characteristics.

[image: Cyclo Dry Moly Lube]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things which could potentially cause you issues with this.

First, you don't know if it is conductive. One of the properties of anti-seize is that it maintains conductivity between the two parts. In this way it works great for spark plugs and O2 sensors. I was reading about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdenum_disulfide#Research) and it was a little beyond my comprehension right now as to it's conductive properties (seems in some places it was suggesting it would and other place it wouldn't conduct electricity ... could be a crap shoot).

The second thing you'd need to worry about (but could easily overcome) is that it is a spray on lubricant. You ***DO NOT*** want to get any of this on the business end of the sensor. If you do, it will surely ruin it.

While I don't normally promote products on here, I will this time ... I usually try to purchase Denso brand O2 sensors because they work pretty well, plus they include a small tube of copper based anti-seize in it. There is enough anti-seize in the tube to do about three or four O2 installs. I wish I could find a large tube of this to use on a regular basis ... it just works great!

Comment: Funny you should mention Denso, since these generic O2's are exactly those in AC Delco disguise. I didn't get any tube with it, probably since the threads came coated with an anemic sliver of anti-seize. Could you expand on the significance of thermal conductivity here?

Comment: Actually I didn't state it, but I meant *electrical* conductivity.

Comment: I'm struggling to think why that would matter.

Comment: A lot of sensors earth through the thing they are screwed into, so have to have a good electrical path through the thread to function properly...

Answer (score 0):

I found this product, it seems to be the right one:

Permatex Copper Anti-Seize -

Electronically conductive, can be used on ground bolts and sensors;

Inhibits rusting, cold welding and galvanic corrosion between assembled parts;

Effective at high temperatures up to 982°C (1800° F);

Ideal applications include: spark plug threads in aluminum blocks, exhaust manifold bolts, engine bolts, oxygen sensor, knock sensor, thermostat housing bolts, fuel filter fitting and battery cable connections;

227g brush-top can

12$ only.

Comment: This is the *more* correct stuff to use.  700 degrees F isn't going to cut it on an O2 sensor.  The "light off" happens around that temperature, and the sensor bung might see upwards of 1500 F.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question acknowledges that anti - seize is the way to go, but what about dry moly?